# NameError: name 'x' is not defined in for loop

Tags: python, list, function, loops, for-loop

New to Python, trying to figure out how to use it.

Using the below piece of code gives me an error:

> NameError: name 'x' is not defined?

Is it related to using `and` in the `for` loop? How can I fix it?

```
lis = list(range(101))
lis1 = lis[::-1]
tot = 0
for i in range(101) and x in lis[:-1]:
    tot = i + x
    print(tot)
```

Comment: I have restructured your question a bit, tried to give it a more meaningful title and added the "Python" tag.

Comment: it is not clear if he wants to sum up elements on the same position of the two lists or if he want to sum up any element of the fist list with any element of the second list.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use

```
lis = list(range(101))
lis1 = lis[::-1]
tot = 0
for i in range(101):
    for x in lis[:-1]:
        tot = i + x
        print(tot)
```